# Access Twitter API from VB.NET

Tags: c#, python, vb.net, twitter

I'm using a python code to make some experiments on Twitter data. My code is something like this (in Python):

```
import twitter;

CONSUMER_KEY='xxxx';
CONSUMER_SECRET='xxxx';
OAUTH_TOKEN = 'xxxx';
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = 'xxxx';
auth = twitter.oauth.OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET,CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
twitter_api = twitter.Twitter(auth=auth);

q = 'mysearch';
count = 15;
search_results = twitter_api.search.tweets(q=q,  count=count,     result_type='popular');
```

What is the best way to have the same functionalities in VB.NET (or C#)? How can I traslate the main functionalities of Twitter Python Package (like twitter.oauth.OAuth function, for ex.)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'best way' to convert from python to .net. Some libraries are ready for the twitter platform, you have many options available at [Twitter Docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries), you will need to use one of them (or write you own ... xD)